# Puppet file URL leads to 'Name or service not known'

Tags: puppet

In /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/send/manifests/init.pp

```
class send {

  file { '/tmp/hello.txt':
  owner  => 'root',
  group  => 'root',
  mode   => '0644',
  source => 'puppet://modules/send/hello.txt',
  }

}
```

In /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/send/files/hello.txt

`puppet agent -t` reports

```
[root@consul-test-02 tmp]# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for consul-test-02
Info: Applying configuration version '1438919627'
Error: /Stage[main]/Send/File[/tmp/hello.txt]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://modules/send/hello.txt: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.03 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL lacks on slash. Use

```
source => 'puppet:///modules/send/hello.txt',
```

Note the triple slash. Your URL had `puppet://modules/...` so it had a *host* portion of `modules`, which (fortunately) does not resolve to an address in your environment.

Comment: Thank you. It work.But I don't understand why the triple slash.

Comment: The host part of the URL is supposed to remain empty, so that Puppet will automatically connect to the master that compiled the catalog. You can also insert a valid host name here if you wish, e.g. `puppet://my.puppet.server/modules/...`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for help again.